# how to enable TLSv1.3 in netty?

Tags: netty, tls1.3

As all the requirements mentioned in https://netty.io/news/2018/10/30/4-1-31-Final.html are met:

> That said TLSv1.3 is not enabled by default so if you want to use it you will need to explicit enable it by using TLSv1.3 when configure your SslContextBuilder (like for example):
>   SslContextBuilder.forClient().protocols("TLSv1.3") ....

but I run into exception as follows:

```html
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:100000f0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at com.taobao.hsf.io.netty.common.tls.NettyHandShakeHandler.channelRead0(NettyHandShakeHandler.java:80)
        at com.taobao.hsf.io.netty.common.tls.NettyHandShakeHandler.channelRead0(NettyHandShakeHandler.java:24)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:454)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
        at com.taobao.hsf.io.netty.util.PooledThreadFactory$PooledByteBufRunnable.run(PooledThreadFactory.java:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:100000f0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1194)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1155)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1226)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1269)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:216)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1297)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1211)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1245)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
        ... 22 more
```

any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way to do it but in this case you enable `TLSv1.3` only which means that the handshake will fail if the server only supports for example `TLSv1.2`. Usually you don't want to only support TLSv1.3 but support also another protocol like `TLSV1.2`.

```
SslContextBuilder.forClient().protocols("TLSv1.3", "TLSv.1.2");
```

Comment: I have tried this way, but TLSv1.2 is used , I also configure server like this `SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).protocols("TLSv1.3", "TLSv1.2")`

Comment: I use self-signed certificate, but the server still uses TLSv1.2. Maybe the certificate   matters. Could you please provide the TLSv1.3 example in project?

Comment: You also need to ensure you set some TLSv1.3 ciphersuite on both sites that work. You can for example see in our unit tests how this works: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.1.31.Final/handler/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SSLEngineTest.java

Answer (score 1):

Netty 4.1.52-Final version has supported TLSv1.3 as default, [refer here](https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/b1d3aad404a39143da7a86c121d60f35c0d21108) for more info.